# Include python tests in JS projects

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, python

Currently I am responsible for test automation and my company develops applications in Node.js. For web applications, I'm using python and selenium-webdriver.

Is there any way to integrate the tests (python) in the JS project?

I confess that it would be easier to automate using webdriverJS, but I see it's hard to find resources and most do not use it.

Comment: Any help about it?

Comment: A quick search returned me [this repo](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell).